# How to access Icons on Mobile screen using TestComplete

Tags: testing, automated-tests, testcomplete

I am new to TestComplete and I have started to work on Mobile Testing. I am trying to access the Icons present on the (Android)Mobile home screen using Object spy. Object spy is detecting the objects of a Java application but not the icons on mobile home screen.

Is there any possible ways to detect them or not.? Please suggest me on this.

Best Regards,
Guru Raja.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that there is a way to recognize these icons as separate objects in the current version of TestComplete. However, you still can work with them using the image-based approach. Find more information on it in the [Image-Based Testing Principles](http://smartbear.com/viewarticle/75229/) help topic.